# What are the upper and lower parts of a non-alphanumeric key called?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For example on my en-US keyboard the question mark '?' is above the forward slash '/'. These are non-alphanumeric symbols so called them upper and lowercase doesn't make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

These are simply called **upper and lower characters** when using the Shift key in combination with that key produces a different result. For example '/' becomes '?' when the Shift key is used on an en-US keyboard. Apple's macOS HIG recommends that the lower key is used for a keyboard shortcut unless Shift is part of that keyboard shortcut.

> **Identify a key with two characters by the lower character, unless
>   Shift is part of the shortcut.** For example, the keyboard shortcut for
>   Hide Status Bar is Command-Slash (that is, Command-/). If the Shift
>   key is part of the keyboard shortcut, identify the key by the upper of
>   the two characters. For example, the keyboard shortcut for Help is
>   Shift-Command-Question Mark, not Shift-Command-Slash.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/Keyboard.html

Comment: I don't believe this is universal terminology. "upper and lower characters" is ambiguous, since all (including en-US) keyboards are not the same - the upper and lower characters can be reversed physically on the keycap. I have always referred to these characters as "shifted and non-shifted characters" - which remains consistent, regardless of the keycap. My keyboard has `/` (upper) above `?` (lower), but the _shifted_ key is still `?`.